# i can't open and collapse my mat-navigation-panel with menuItem.type==='dropDown'

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Using this it open and close all the dropdown menu type at the same time.

```
         <mat-expansion-panel #panel  (click)="colapse()"
           [expanded]="expansionPanelClosed" 
                     *ngIf="menuItem.type==='dropDown'"  class="nav-expansion-panel">
                     <mat-expansion-panel-header style="font-size: 16px;">
                       <mat-panel-title>
                         <mat-icon>{{menuItem.iconType}}</mat-icon>
                         {{ menuItem.title | translate }}
                       </mat-panel-title>
                     </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                     <mat-list dense class="mat-expansion-panel-body">

                       <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let subMenu of menuItem.children">

                         <app-menu-list-item [subMenu]="subMenu"></app-menu-list-item>

                       </mat-nav-list>

                     </mat-list>

                   </mat-expansion-panel>
```

sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu?file=app%2Fmenu-list-item%2Fmenu-list-item.component.html

Comment: try [expanded]="false"

Comment: then we use one equal '=' :  *ngIf="menuItem.type = 'dropDown'"